# How can I share Amazon S3 content with MFA protection via IAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I like to share my [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) private content with members. Initially I did that by creating an [AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) user account, but people started to pass these credentials around.

So I found I can hand out a [AWS Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA)](http://aws.amazon.com/mfa/) token/fob to each user account created via IAM. However, testing reveals that I can still download files, S3 will not ask for the 6-digits number generated by the token/fob.

What am I missing here? Or if I went down the wrong path, please suggest a way to detect/prevent members sharing these credentials. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specifically [Configure MFA-Protected API Access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/MFAProtectedAPI.html) for the resource you are trying to protect (i.e. the S3 content in your case), see the introductory blog post about [MFA-Protected API Access](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/07/new-aws-feature-mfa-protected-api-access.html) for an overview how this feature works.

Fortunately there are a few examples for [Adding a Bucket Policy to Require MFA Authentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html#AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCase7_s3) available - please read that section for details, but the first example addresses your use case already (the third one extends it by adding a condition to *limit the duration for which the aws:MultiFactorAuthAge key is valid*):

```js
{
   "Version": "2008-10-17",
   "Id": "123",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "",
         "Effect": "Deny",
         "Principal": { "AWS": "*" },
         "Action": "s3:**",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/taxdocuments/*",
         "Condition": { "Null": { "aws:MultiFactorAuthAge": true }}
      }
   ]
}
```